# CustomArrayAdapter Implementation:Unable to get the resource id

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I want to implement CustomArrayAdapter and following is the constructor I have written for my custom adapter

```
public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
     }
```

The second argument in the super call The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views. I dont know which resource ID is being referred here. Can anyone please explain in detail which resource ID is being referred here.

My overridden getView method is as follows :-

```
 @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        User user = getItem(position);    
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvName.setText(user.name);
        tvHome.setText(user.hometown);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: that's your layout id,you can pass it through constructor or directly insert it there.

Comment: second arg is your ListView row layout id as what you are using in your getView() also.

Comment: i have edited my question to include the getView method . . can you please tell is this the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 I dont know which resource ID is being referred here.
```

Since you put `0` in the second parameter of the constructor it wont have any reference to any layout

as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)) is saying:

```
 resource   The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
```

Now if you put an existing layout to the constructor then that layout will be use to instantiate the view of your `listViewItems` but you need to override the `getView` method to enable you to design which text goes where in your layout.

If you are planning to put an existing layout then use another constructor on it:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

But for design I wont really add any resource layout to the constructor but directly **inflate** the view in your `getView` method and return that view.

Comment: i have edited my question to include the getView method . . can you please tell is this the right approach?

Comment: @AnkitGarg the right approach is a viewHolder pattern. which is fast.

Comment: @AnkitGarg go to this link to learn how to implement View holder pattern http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: can you provide me some sample code on github for the same if you have ?

Comment: @AnkitGarg just follow the pattern on how to implement voew holder pattern it will increase the performance of your listView

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Do you think you could help me with this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549679/how-can-i-split-a-long-single-sqliteopenhelper-into-serveral-classes-one-for-e

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
class CustomUsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    pArrayList<User> users;


    public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.context = context;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvHometown;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return users.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_user, null);
            holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
            holder.tvHometown = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHometown);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvName.setText(users.get(position).name);
        holder.tvHometown.setText(users.get(position).hometown);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is implemented of baseadapter by viewholder I suppose, which is faster than the approach adopted by me earlier. I am correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to us your layout file in that constructor. So you need to change your constructor from

```
public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
 }
```

to

```
public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, int resLayout , ArrayList<User> users) {
    super(context, resLayout , users);
 }
```

`resLayout`  is the ID for your layout xml file which will be in your custom adapter class.

And the Syntax for `ArrayAdapter` is

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

For more info you can check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: i have edited my question to include the getView method . . can you please tell is this the right approach?

Comment: you just need to change your adapter constructor where you have set adapter to your listview what i have changed in my  answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're going to use your `ArrayAdapter` for, but one reason for using an `ArrayAdapter` is to display a `listView` of a layout depending on the array.

Here is an example of what the constructor should look like

```
public CustomListAdapter() {
    super(Activity_Main.class, R.layout.listview_item, array);
}
```

Here is what could be in your listview_item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:id="@+id/name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, the `CustomListAdapter` will generate X number of `listview_item` layouts height wise in a `ListView`, where X is the size of `array`.

Hope this helps.