# Showing data from Arraylist of Hashmap

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I'm getting json data and putting it in hashmap and hashmap into an arraylist. All is happening in fragment extending ListFragment

```
  protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        try {

            jsonObject.put("full_name", etUserSearch.getText().toString());
            responseReceive = JsonPostClient.SendHttpPost(urls[0],
                    jsonObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Success = responseReceive.getJSONArray("Success");

            for (int i = 0; i < Success.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = Success.getJSONObject(i);

                String full_name = c.getString(TAG_FULL_NAME);
                String user_name = c.getString(TAG_USER_NAME);
                String user_id = c.getString(TAG_USER_ID);

                HashMap<String, String> friends = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                friends.put(TAG_FULL_NAME, full_name);
                friends.put(TAG_USER_NAME, user_name);
                friends.put(TAG_USER_ID, user_id);

                // adding contact to contact list
                FriendSearchList.add(friends);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("hello", "");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        printFriends();
    };
```

I'm checking that data is valid by printFriends() method and wanna show only 'TAG_FULL_NAME' data in a listview. My ListView initialization

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_add_friends, container,
            false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Method for checking data and loading in ListView

```
 public void printFriends() {
    int len = FriendSearchList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String f_name = FriendSearchList.get(i).get(TAG_FULL_NAME);
        String u_name = FriendSearchList.get(i).get(TAG_USER_NAME);
        String u_id = FriendSearchList.get(i).get(TAG_USER_ID);

        Log.d("full_name", f_name);
        Log.d("user_name", u_name);
        Log.d("user_id", u_id);
    }


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
            FriendSearchList, R.layout.tab_addfriend_list,
            new String[] { TAG_FULL_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.full_name });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

tab_add_friends xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

tab_addfriend_list xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<!-- Name Label -->

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/full_name"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingBottom="2dip"
       android:paddingTop="6dip"
       android:textColor="#43bd00"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

There is no error showing just nothing is showing into listview. Need suggestion or clue to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375831/customarrayadapter-implementationunable-to-get-the-resource-id/25376257#25376257 and use HashMap instead of User Class.

Comment: why don't you use custom adapter? or make MyUser class and override toString() method, in that just put "TAG_FULL_NAME" and add this class to arraylist

Comment: @GiGa thnx for suggestion. i thought it should work but i'm trying also other ways

Comment: I had the same problem when I extended from ListActivity then It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem once
**the problem** is you are feeding the data using simple adapter but you may be inflate the rowView outside the ui thread and feed the from the post execute . thtas why your view dont getting the data . actually you dont have to inflate the rowview here is the hole code for you .Another thing print friend method also useless just initialize the simple adapter in the onPostExecute() method.

`public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";


private boolean isConnection = false;

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oflineContactList;

private MyContactDataSource dataSource;

List<Contatcs> oflineContatcs;
```

// private ListAdapter adapter1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    dataSource = new MyContactDataSource(MainActivity.this); 
    dataSource.open();




    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();



    oflineContactList = dataSource.getContatcs();


    Log.i("data", oflineContactList.toString());
        ListView lv = getListView();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, oflineContactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                        TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.email,
                        R.id.name, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);




    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    new GetContacts().execute();


}



private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Data is loading...please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler mHandler = new ServiceHandler();


        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = mHandler.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

         Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

         if(jsonStr != null){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                //Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                 // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);


                 // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                 // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                 // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);

                }
                dataSource.creareContacts(contactList);
                dataSource.close();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


         }
         else {
             Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if(pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

         /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                 MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                            TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

         setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an Arraylist of HashMap where `SimpleAdapter` wont have any idea on which data is to put in the layout of the ListView items.

You can use this to implement items in your `ListView`

**sample:**

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                                            FriendSearchList, R.layout.tab_addfriend_list,
                                            new String[] { TAG_FULL_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.full_name }){
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return FriendSearchList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_addfriend_list, parent);
                TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
                tx.setText(FriendSearchList.get(i).get(TAG_FULL_NAME));
            } else 
                v = convertView;

            return v;
        }
    };
```