# how to show data in Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created two `textview` and one `editText` in my second Custom `ListView`, i want to set value name , rate,quant in my custom `listView` one by one which is already show on `Toast`,also I have first `listView` which have  5 Value  which i have to show on Second Custom `listView` on Button `onClick()` Event..

```
    int count = lisView1.getAdapter().getCount();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
    LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i); // Find by under       LinearLayout
    TextView itemname = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    TextView rat = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.rat);
    EditText quan = (EditText)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    String     rate = rat.getText().toString();
    String  quant = quan.getText().toString();
    String     name = itemname.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(Mmnue.this,name + ", " + rate+ " , " +quant   ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


    }
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375831/customarrayadapter-implementationunable-to-get-the-resource-id/25376257#25376257

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a for-loop for this.

You need to use  **`getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`**

I suggest you read some tutorials on Custom Adapters in ListView.

**[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)** puts it very simply. Easy to understand.

And **[this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example)** should go a long way in helping you to work with ListViews.